# Import DataTableHeader typescript type of Vuetify3 v-data-table

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuejs3, vuetify.js, vuetifyjs3

I cannot import the type definition DataTableHeader for v-data-table headers. Currently, I have written it like this:

```
import { DataTableHeader } from 'vuetify/types';
```

In the TypeScript error, it says

> Cannot find module 'vuetify/types' or its corresponding type declarations.

Does anyone know a solution to this problem?

Answer (score 28):

The DataTableHeaders type is currently not exported (as of Vuetify 3.5.5). My guess is that this will change in the future, but in the meantime, you can still extract it from the `VDataTable`.

#### Vuetify 3.5 (current)

Since v3.3, headers are deep readonly. We can undo the readonly, but not without changing the type, which makes it incompatible with the initial DataTableHeader declaration and requires an additional type assertion when assigning to the v-data-table.

So **if you know you won't change the headers** after declaration, I would just use the readonly declaration:

```
import type { VDataTable } from 'vuetify/components'

type ReadonlyHeaders = VDataTable['$props']['headers']

const headers: ReadonlyHeaders = [...]
```

This will give you an array type (`DataTableHeader[]`). If you want the item type, you can further unwrap it:

```
import type { VDataTable } from 'vuetify/components'

type ReadonlyHeaders = VDataTable['$props']['headers']
type UnwrapReadonlyArray<A> = A extends Readonly<Array<infer I>> ? I : never;
type ReadonlyDataTableHeader = UnwrapReadonlyArrayType<ReadonlyHeaders>;

const headers: ReadonlyDataTableHeader[] = [...]
```

(the `UnwrapReadonlyArray` utility type unwraps the readonly array and throws away the possible `undefined`)

However, this turned out to need updating between Vuetify versions, while the array version did not. If possible, stick to the array version to avoid maintenance.

---

**If you need to change the headers after declaration**, you can make them mutable with another utility class:

```
type DeepMutable<T> = { -readonly [P in keyof T]: DeepMutable<T[P]> }
type DataTableHeader = DeepMutable<ReadonlyDataTableHeader>;
```

(the `DeepMutable` utility class maps the input type recursively to a new type, removing any `readonly` modifiers)

Now if you assign a `DataTableHeader[]` to the `:headers` prop TS will complain that a `DeepMutable[]` can't be assigned to a `DeepReadonly[]`, but since we already know the types match, we can just tell it to shut up:

```html
<v-data-table
  :headers="(headers as any)"
```

---

#### Vuetify 3.3

Up until v3.3, VDataTable was still in labs, so the component had to be imported from `vuetify/labs/components`. Also, Vuetify did not export a type, but only the constructor function:

```
import type { VDataTable } from 'vuetify/labs/components'

type Headers = InstanceType<typeof VDataTable>['headers']
```

(`VDataTable` is a constructor function, so we turn it into a type with `typeof`, get the type it constructs with `InstanceType` and then get the `headers` prop by index)

The array type did not include `undefined`, but could be an array of arrays. So unwrapping the item type was slightly different:

```
type UnwrapReadonlyArrayType<A> = A extends Readonly<Array<infer I>> ? UnwrapReadonlyArrayType<I> : A
type ReadonlyDataTableHeader = UnwrapReadonlyArrayType<Headers>;
```

(the `UnwrapArrayType` recursively extracts the item type from an array type until no array is left and we have the `DataTableHeader`)

As with 3.4, this gives you readonly types, which can be unwrapped as above.

---

#### Until Vuetify 3.3

Headers were not readonly, otherwise it is the same as above:

```
import { VDataTable } from 'vuetify/labs/components'

type Headers = InstanceType<typeof VDataTable>['headers'] // gives `DataTableHeader[] | DataTableHeader[][]`
// optionally unwrap DataTableHeader
type UnwrapArrayType<A> = A extends Array<infer I> ? UnwrapArrayType<I> : A
type DataTableHeader = UnwrapArrayType<Headers>
```

Comment: I t worked for me. After importing the VDataTable and creating the 3 types as you suggested I just added my heaader like 'const headers: ReadonlyDataTableHeader[] = [...' and run yarn vue-tsc to check. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: Does not seem to work anymore with Vuetify 3.4 :(

Comment: Thank you @Finrod, I updated the answer for 3.4 (location of the component changed and `headers` prop can be `undefined`)

Comment: Does not work from v3.5.5. It seems `headers` now nested in `$props`: `type ReadonlyHeaders = VDataTable['$props']['headers']`

Answer (score 4):

Vuetify defines the DataTableHeaders type at `lib/labs/components.d.ts` but it is not exported for external use.
You can define your own type by copying this type to use in your component.

```js
type DataTableHeader = {
    key: string;
    value?: SelectItemKey;
    title: string;
    colspan?: number;
    rowspan?: number;
    fixed?: boolean;
    align?: 'start' | 'end';
    width?: number;
    minWidth?: string;
    maxWidth?: string;
    sortable?: boolean;
    sort?: DataTableCompareFunction;
};

const headers:DataTableHeader  = [
    { title: 'The title', key: 'the_key' },
  ]
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm using this to control visibility:

```
type ReadonlyHeaders = InstanceType<typeof VDataTable>['headers']
```

and `headerProps` + `cellProps`:

```
const hideColumn = ref<boolean>(true)

const headers = ref<ReadonlyHeaders>([
  {
    key: 'column1',
    cellProps: hideColumn.value ? { style: 'display: none' } : undefined,
    headerProps: hideColumn.value ? { style: 'display: none' } : undefined
  }
])
```

or you can write a helper:

```
const hideTableColumn = (val: boolean = true) => {
  const dn = { style: 'display:none' }
  return val
    ? {
        headerProps: dn,
        cellProps: dn
      }
    : undefined
}
```

and use it:

```
const headers = ref<ReadonlyHeaders>([
  {
    key: 'column1',
    ...hideTableColumn()
  }
])
```

or

```
...hideTableColumn(hideColumn)
```

but unfortenutelly it's not reactive :(