# How to import TypeScript types in Vuetify 3?

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuetify.js, vuetifyjs3

I would like to use the type `ValidationRule` (see [docs](https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/blob/master/packages/vuetify/src/composables/validation.ts#L16-L20) and [source code](https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/blob/master/packages/vuetify/src/composables/validation.ts#L16-L20)) but I cannot find a way how to import them in my Vue.js component.

I tried import the type in ways like this:

```
import type { ValidationRule } from 'vuetify/types'
```

But this does not work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently, Vuetify does not export the type. But you can extract it from component declarations, similar to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75993081/4883195):

```
import type { VTextField } from 'vuetify/components'

type UnwrapReadonlyArray<A> = A extends Readonly<Array<infer I>> ? I : A;
type ValidationRule = UnwrapReadonlyArray<VTextField['rules']>
```

Doesn't really matter which component you use, as long as it uses the `ValidationRule` type. VTextField has a [`:rules`](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-text-field/#props-rules) prop, so I am using that.
Using the `rules` index gives the type `readonly ValidationRule[]`.
Finally, the `UnwrapReadonlyArray` type is used to extract the array item type and remove the readonly modifier.

---

**Before Vuetify 3.4**, constructor functions were exported rather than types, so you had to build the type yourself:

```
type VTextFieldType = InstanceType<typeof VTextField>
type ValidationRule = UnwrapReadonlyArray<VTextFieldType['rules']>
```

Comment: This works well for me. Thanks :-)
It is a bit strange that there is no clean way to do that, but it will probably come at one point.

Comment: That's great! Yes, I hope so too. While it is fun to screw around with Typescript, it really shouldn't be necessary